# Unable to Update Webpack for React Project

Tags: npm, webpack

Right now my current project is using an old version of webpack (3.5.1) and I need to update it to a version that can understand object spread because an npm module would not compile because of older webpack version.

If I run `npm update webpack` I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: css-loader@1.0.1
npm ERR! Found: webpack@3.5.1
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   webpack@"3.5.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"2 || 3" from babel-loader@7.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/babel-loader
npm ERR!     babel-loader@"7.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   10 more (extract-text-webpack-plugin, file-loader, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from css-loader@1.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/css-loader
npm ERR!   dev css-loader@"1.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@4.46.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from css-loader@1.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/css-loader
npm ERR!     dev css-loader@"1.0.1" from the root project
```

I tried to force update but it didn't work either.

Comment: Can you provide the webpack config? Your package versions are most likely incompatible.

Comment: Hi @Kriss. I made a new [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71555443/npm-build-error-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type). This time I just mentioned the error that I am having when I run `npm run build`. I included my webpack config and package.json.